# Firebase storage upload progress inaccurate

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

There is a problem with the onProgress function that is overrided by addOnProgressListener.

My problem is that the TaskSnapshot when I try to upload an image does not return the bytes that have been transferred. It just stays at 0. Here is a snippet of code that I have for this:

```
StorageReference myStorageRef = momentsStorageRef.child(momentID + ".jpeg");

UploadTask uploadTask = myStorageRef.putBytes(data, new StorageMetadata.Builder()
       .setContentType("image/jpeg")
       .build());



uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
   @Override
   public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
       int bytesTransferred = (int) taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred();
       int totalBytes = (int) taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();



       int progress = (100 *  bytesTransferred) / totalBytes ;
       Log.v(TAG, "Bytes transferred: " + taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred());
       Log.v(TAG, "TotalBytes: " + totalBytes);
       Log.v(TAG, "Upload is: " + progress + "% done");
       mBuilder.setProgress(100, progress, false);


       mNotifyManager.notify(APPLICATION_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
   }
})
```

Here is the logCat:

> 05-28 19:21:33.911 27673-27673: Bytes transferred: 0 
>  05-28 
>   19:21:33.911 27673-27673: TotalBytes: 205846 
>  05-28 19:21:33.911
>   27673-27673: Upload is: 0% done 
> 05-28 19:21:35.637 27673-27673: Bytes
>   transferred: 0 
> 05-28 19:21:35.637 27673-27673: TotalBytes: 205846 
>   05-28 19:21:35.637 27673-27673: Upload is: 0% done 
>  05-28 19:21:41.458
>   27673-27673 Bytes transferred: 205846 
> 05-28 19:21:41.458 27673-27673
>   TotalBytes: 205846 
>  05-28 19:21:41.458 27673-27673: Upload is: 100%
>   done

Answer (score 9):

*firebaser here*

The progress is measured in chunks of 256KB. Since your file is smaller than that, it fits in one chunk and progress thus jumps from 0% to 100% in one go.

We have an open task to improve the granularity of the progress measurement in the case of smaller files and lower bandwidth connections.

Comment: Okay Frank. Thank you for letting me know. Please update me when this task is completed or a link to github, where I can watch it or contribute to it. Thanks.

Comment: my file is 4 mb.. i am calculating the progress percentage by ( getBytesTransferred()/totalCount() * 100) but its taking 100% at one go

Comment: That sounds like a concrete problem with your code. I recommend you open a new question with the [minimal complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That way someone can see precisely what *you* are doing, and hopefully spot the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have images of 16KB  or max 50KB... is there any update on granularity of the progress measurement?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Any change to this would show in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) of the SDK you use.

Answer (score 1):

According to firebase storage documentation, they return the progress values in double like 0.13,0.15,0.24,0.55 etc .Since you are casting to int type it always returns 0. So the solution is dont cast to int just store it in double

double progress=(taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred())/taskSnapshot.getTotalBytesCount);
System.out.println(progress*100 +"");