# Firebase Cloud Storage Upload Progress (<256kb)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Assuming [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#full_example) as your code to upload.

```
// File or Blob named mountains.jpg
var file = ...

// Create the file metadata
var metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg'
};

// Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/' + file.name).put(file, metadata);

// Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
  function(snapshot) {
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
    var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
        console.log('Upload is paused');
        break;
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
        console.log('Upload is running');
        break;
    }
  }, function(error) {

  // A full list of error codes is available at
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'storage/unauthorized':
      // User doesn't have permission to access the object
      break;

    case 'storage/canceled':
      // User canceled the upload
      break;

    ...

    case 'storage/unknown':
      // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
      break;
  }
}, function() {
  // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
  uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
  });
});
```

How do you indicate progress (using the console) when:

- Your users have an unreliable/unpredictable slow internet connection (<50kb/s)
- Upload small files (<.5mb)

'state_changed' Event seems to fires for progress chunks of 250kb. Can't find anything about this in the official [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask).

Can I reduce the chunk size somehow or get regular updates every second?

Any other workarounds are highly appreciated.

P.S.: Every user's connection will be different, I will not assume 50kb/s and just show static progress based on assumption.

Comment: If you have code to show, please copy the relevant parts into the question itself.  Please don't link out to external resources.

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/sjNn5f2Qdb4

Comment: Progress is reported in chunks of 256KB. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505375/firebase-storage-upload-progress-inaccurate. There is no way to change this reporting interval/size at the moment.